# force_eeprom_read=0, but RPi4 still stuck at rainbow screen

Tags: gpio, pi-4, hardware, boot-issues, pi4-eeprom

I have made a custom PCB/Hat for a Raspberry Pi and I need to use **ID_SD** and **ID_SC** as general GPIOs. At the moment Raspberry Pi 4 gets stuck at Rainbow screen when booting (with Raspberry Pi 3B+ everything is fine and the Raspberry starts up when the PCB is connected to it).

I added the line **force_eeprom_read=0** to **/boot/config.txt**, which should prevent scanning I2C HAT EEPROM, but in my case that does not help. The **RPi4 still does not boot up** and is stuck at the boot screen. (Followed this thread: [More information about GPIO0 and GPIO1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111312/more-information-about-gpio0-and-gpio1/114051#114051))

I have narrowed it down to the pin nr 28 which ID_SC (or GPIO1). There is a voltage divider connected to this pin consisting of a 5,1k and 10k resistors (VCC---5,1k--GPIO1--10k---GND). It is meant for a water flow sensor and if it is not connected the pin is drawn to the GND level. If a sensor is connected it could be either 3.3V or 0V at the startup.

I just want / need to turn off the EEPROM scanning, if force_eeprom_read=0 to config.txt did not work, **what should I do? (or try next)**

**Do I have to create a custom device-tree-overlay?** Will that help? Changing the hardware would be the last option (my board is using all the pins). I believe that a nice solution would be to turn off / prevent the EEPROM scanning.

Answer (score 0):

You are out of luck. It can't be done with a Pi4.

See my answer in the linked question - the I²C bus is used for other things on Pi3 & Pi4 (I suspect controlled by Video Core).

These pins can be used for some purposes; I have used for UART.